# How to split text into another page if the text is large in table?

Tags: php, html, mpdf

My code looks like this:

```
$html = '<table style="width: 793px; overflow: wrap" autosize="1">
   <tr>
       <td>small text</td>
       <td>large text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>small text</td>
       <td>large text</td>
   </tr>
</table';

$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

I don't know why, but mpdf tries to put one TR on one page. But if text is large in TD, mpdf automatically resizes the font size to very small. I need to split my text on two pages without changing the font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented behaviour](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html):

> Note: mPDF will always resize tables if it is the only way to fit a row or whole table onto a full page.

Split large text to multiple rows if you need it to span between pages. Or don't use tables.

Comment: Thx, but I don't know how to build table without the <table> tag. I can try to use <div> blocks, but without CSS styles like this: "display: inline-block, flex or other" it's very hard. For example:
 
<div style="width:100%;border:1px solid #000">
   <div style="float:left;width:48%;border-right:1px solid #000">small text</div>
   <div style="float:right;width:48%">large text <br/>large text</div>
</div>

border-right is not responsive

Comment: Would columns help? https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/columns.html